# React 'Invariant Violation' in typescript application

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting the following error when trying to use react-collapse ([repository](https://github.com/nkbt/react-collapse)) component in my typescript application with self-made d.ts file:

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).

and

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

index.d.ts:

```
declare namespace ReactCollapse {
    export class Collapse extends __React.Component<any, any> { }
}
declare module "react-collapse" {
    export = ReactCollapse;
}
```

Original index.js from react-collapse:

```
'use strict';
const Collapse = require('./Collapse').default;
module.exports = Collapse;
```

Application code:

```
import { Collapse } from 'react-collapse';
const render = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Collapse isOpened={true}>One</Collapse>,
        document.getElementById('test-container')
    );
}
render();
```

I am using typescript 1.8.10, redux-collapse was installed via npm and tsc uses commonjs generation. Application is built using webpack. I am pretty sure, that I have mistakes in my .d.ts file, but I just can't figure it out.

**UPDATE 1:**

Tried to add render method to typing like Hunter suggested, so typing now looks like this:

```
declare namespace ReactCollapse {
    export class Collapse extends __React.Component<any, any> {
        public render(): JSX.Element;
    }
}
declare module "react-collapse" {
     export = ReactCollapse;
}
```

But I am still getting the same error.

**UPDATE 2:**

Somehow, I managed to fix error with next typing and module resolution call:

index.d.ts:

```
declare class Collapse extends __React.Component<any, any> {}

declare module "react-collapse" {   
    export = Collapse;
}
```

Code:

```
import Collapse = require('react-collapse');
const render = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Collapse isOpened={true}>One</Collapse>,
        document.getElementById('test-container')
    );
}
render();
```

But, the thing is - it was a random guess, and I don't understand why it works. So, maybe anyone can explain it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in the index.js we can see that the original index.js exports **just the class** as the export value, not any wrapper around it.

In the first version of the code, you declare that the value exported is the namespace (so, a wrapper, containing the class inside), so the `import { Collapse } from 'react-collapse'` expects to get smth like `{ Collapse: { /* the component class here*/ } }`, but in reality gets just the inner `{ /* the component class here*/ }`. Then you try to use a prop on it named `Collapse` (which is `undefined`) and pass it to the React, getting the error.

The second version declares (correctly) that the export value is the class itself, and imports it directly, without the `{ xxx }` decomposing syntax, so - no surprise - it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your Collapse component has no `render()`

Comment: Tried to add render method declaration in typing - still the same error

Comment: Ok, so render has to be a function that returns something like JSX.Element.